# Is there a control in WPF like FlowDocumentReader, but editable?

Tags: wpf

Is there a control in WPF like FlowDocumentReader with search functionality, but editable and have a formatbar like RichTextBox?

Answer (score 3):

In WPF you are able to use the RichTextBox with an FlowDocument inside.
For editing with formats and colors you can use things like this 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50139/WPF-RichTextEditor-with-Toolbar

Answer (score 0):

There are third-pary controls, Telerik has a particularly nice one that I've used before: http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/richtextbox.aspx.

But there aren't any in the BCL.